# What is my Azure storage name for data export?

Tags: azure

I created storage in Azure. Now it shows

```
Deployment name:b87171ex_1627388132338
```

Bellow

```
default (b87171ex/default)
```

It also has `Subscription ID`.

From OPENAPI(my PROJECT)

[image]

What is my Storage resource name that I should use for data exports?

Comment: Please add more specifics. It's not clear what you're referring to.

Comment: @NoahStahl Take a look,please. I must set type,resource name and resource group.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what this is about. If you wrote some background context about what you are doing and how you arrived at this point, perhaps that would make it clear.